# Plotting multiple series on a line/bar graph with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a plot of a line and bar on the same graph. I'm close, but I can't solve a few items. Here's what I have so far...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({'Value1': np.arange(80, 180, 1),
                     'Value2': np.arange(1.5, .5, -0.01)},
                    index=np.arange(10, 110, 1))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

data['Value1'].plot(ax=ax)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
data['Value2'].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2, color='y', ylim=(0, 3))
```

[image: ExampleGraph]

So the problems I have with this graph are...

1. The x-ticks look awful. If I only do a line graph, the x-ticks look fine. As soon as I add the `twinx` axis however, the major/minor ticks logic get's dropped. How can I keep that?
2. My x-axes is numeric. Note that the line intercepts the x-axis at the value "10" (its hard to see, but that's what's going on). I presume this is because the line's x-axis is supposed to begin at "10" and the bar's x-axis begins at 10 as well, but there's confusion of the value and label so the line's x-axis get's pushed over the label "20".

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Bar plot and line plot has different X coordinate range is different, consider using two x coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to save `xticks` and `xtickslabels` after `data['Value1'].plot(ax=ax)` and set them back after `data['Value2'].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2, color='y', ylim=(0, 3))`:

```
data['Value1'].plot(ax=ax)
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
xlabels = [x.get_text() for x in ax.get_xticklabels()]


ax2 = ax.twinx()
data['Value2'].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2, color='y', ylim=(0, 3))

ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)

plt.show()
```